# Stochastic gradient methods and risk of neural nets

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, ai.artificial-intel, stochastic-process

Under many situations it is currently provable that we can minimize the risk of neural nets using stochastic gradient based algorithms. For example : https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03804, https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.04918 https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.03962, https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12065, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.02054.pdf, https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04591 and dozens more!

Is the focus on stochastic gradient based methods for this question purely motivated by the fact that this is pretty much the only thing used in practice?

Or is there a fundamental/complexity-theoretic reason why there cant be an algorithm (or its improbably hard to find an algorithm) that does not use stochastic gradients (is maybe deterministic!) and yet minimizes the risk of neural nets as fast as one can using SGD-like methods?

Comment: You should first ask, Why is SGD used in practice? The answer has to do with memory efficiency and parallelizability.

Comment: Yes. And is the claim that its impossible to get such benefits without stochastic gradients?

Comment: That would be a *very* strong claim to make! I am not aware of anyone claiming that.

Comment: Indeed it would be strong! I am wondering if there is any theoretical proof which makes stochastic gradient based algorithms for risk minimization look somewhat inevitable.

Comment: Well, you would need a reduction showing that any risk minimizer in this setting is essentially performing SGD as a byproduct. Like I said, I’m not aware of any such results.

Comment: So are there run-time lowerbounds on any kind of risk minimization?

Comment: Sure, the problem is NP-hard in general. Hard to approximate even, in the case of nearest-neighbor sample compression (see Thm. 4 here
https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~karyeh/semimetric-j.pdf
)

Comment: Thanks. But why is Theorem 4 a theorem of the kind I am looking for? I was imagining a theorem of this kind "Given a class of algorithms A and an epsilon >0 and a loss class L and a data distributions D, one cannot use algorithms of type A to find a member of L whose generalization error is below epsilon  unless running time is f(epsilon)"  (..the "loss class" L is like say squared losses on some net architecture so that the members of L are parameterized by the weights of L..)

Comment: You asked for run-time lower bounds, but we only know how to prove reductions from NP-hard problems, which is what Thm. 4 is.

Comment: Interesting. So you mean that the only notion of hardness of risk minimization known is when we can relate that to some NP-hardness equation? So we dont have any "unconditional" hardness theorems which are like the statement I was imagining : which would say that for some class of algorithms a certain risk minimization is hard to do.

Comment: It's rare that "study of X is *purely* motivated by Y", and it is rare to find results of the form "it is *impossible* to get benefits B without method M", so I don't think it's very useful to ask for that or expect it to hold in this context -- that seems like asking for an awful lot.

Comment: Yes. It seems like. I wanted to know if there are any theoretical arguments which make the prevalent method of risk minimization somehow look "inevitable". Interprete my question as what is the "closest" to such an inevitability of stochastic gradients kind of proof do we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has changed somewhat in the comments, so I'll address its new version: "Given a class of algorithms $A$ and an $\epsilon >0$ and a loss class $L$ and a data distribution $D$, one cannot use algorithms of type $A$ to find a member of $L$ whose generalization error is below $\epsilon$ unless running time is $f(\epsilon)$"... .

One such lower bound I'm aware of is for the case of Statistical Query based algorithms. See, for example, the paper by Yang, "New lower bounds for statistical query learning",
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000004001291
where, in particular,
it is shown that "any SQ-based algorithm needs running time $\Omega(2^n)$".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was also beginning to think in this direction. So is stochastic gradient descent a SQ-type algorithm?

Comment: Hmm, I tend to think "yes" but not 100% sure about that. Have a look at this paper and if you still have questions, try contacting one of the authors: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2488608.2488692